# Access variables defined in main thread in second thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my C# console application, I start a new task and call a function that requires me to be able to access variables that were defined in the main thread, for example:

```
class Example
{
    static int ExampleVarForQuestion = 1;
    int Main()
    {
        new Task(WhereProblemOccures.ExampleFunction).Start();
    }
}

class WhereProblemOccures
{
    static int ExampleFunction()
    {
        if(Example.ExampleVarForQuestion == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above variable value `ExampleVarForQuestion` is not able to be reached in `ExampleVarForQuestion()`. I'm quite new to C#, so if this question wasn't worded very good sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to be reached it must be public as your method is defined in another class.

Note that if the member is going to be written by another thread you should add some form of synchronization to guarantee thread safety.

Comment: @C0d1ng I'm glad it helped you out. If it answered your question don't forget to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I'm going to after 5 mins :) It says i have to wait another 5 minutes before i can mark your question as a "Answer" :/